# canot call userinfo due to invalid scope error

Tags: asp.net, oauth, asp.net-identity-2, identityserver3

I am setting up identity server3 with Microsoft identity stored in ef 6
I can "login" at the /token  end point but when I try to access the /userinfo I get a scope error.
when I try to add scopes to my /token login they do not work.
tried to edit the client to add the scopes and still stuck.
the client is the resource owner flow.
just need to get userinfo so I can get the name and the roles for the user.

1) what scope do I need to access the user info end point ? I get insufficient scope on all my attempts.
2) I have editied the sql database and the code to allow my client to have more scopes but it does not seem to work. how to debug that ?

also I am using asp.net identity stored in sql and the id server ef to store tokens, clients, scopes and secrets, well I am trying to but I am not sure it's right.  the tables were created but I do not see any rows in the tokens table event though I was issued a token.   I have two databases right now: one with the token/client/scope stuff and the other with aspnet users and roles.
do I need to make this one database ?

it looks like part of my problem is with the identity server sample for using entity framework to store the clients, scopes and related data.
it looks like some items are missing in the lists of scopes and or scope claims and or clients, so when I try to login with a scope parameter I get rejected when it can not find the row in the scopes table.
working on how to fix this and I hope get it working....

does a scope need scope claims ?? need to see if I can find info on that.

Answer (score 0):

its 'openid' scope as docs say. https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/endpoints/userinfo.html

Comment: Ok this helps a bit but still leaves me stuck, I did get the scope opened to work with a token request but the user info endpoint only gave me back a subject id, so I tried to add "roles" to my scope and I can't get a login at /token, invalid scope error.

Comment: Enable and check the logs then. It will contain all your errors so you can debug and diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have the issue solved and will post the answer as soon as I can, source debugging helped me trace out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt I just download the current source code from Github and apply breakpoints, rather than using the Nuget package.

**Just going from memory (So this may not be completely accurate).**

I believe the UserInfoEndpoint makes a call to UserService.GetProfileDataAsync. The UserInfoEndpoint is accepting scopes but the GetProfileDataAsync only accepts claims as "RequestedClaimTypes". So somewhere in between it will be taking the scopes sent to endpoint and getting a list of all claim types that fall within the scopes.

The most important thing to keep in mind here is that the scopes you pass into the UserInfoEndpoint must be Identity scopes. The endpoint will not return claims belonging to resource scopes.

**So just a quick rundown...**

1. Server receives scopes sent to UserInfoEndpoint
2. Of the scopes received, it only looks at Identity Scopes
3. Find claim types that are assigned to the identity scopes
4. Passes down the list of claim types to GetProfileDataAsync as "context.RequestedClaimTypes".
5. At this point your custom logic determines how the RequestedClaimTypes translate into IssuedClaims.

My guess is that you are passing in resource scopes to the UserInfoEndpoint.

Answer (score 0):

what finally got my problem fixed:
I needed more scopes in my sql database , the id server sample for v3 using entity framework did not have some of the same scope items that the  identity server sample expects , this was making a login token call fail with invalid scope.
I edited the c# code for the scopes and clients to get what I needed and dropped and re-created the sql tables and then it started working.
I also added a new scope and scope claims to add in non standard claims that our app needs.

I did attach the source to let me debug that really helped as I could follow the logic and see where it did not work. that was a huge help.
I will see later if I can post to the source what the sample was missing that was the real problem.
it might also be good if we had some kind of guide on how to get the standard userinfo / profile claims to work.  I got it but that also was a bit of source debugging to see how the id server calls to the stores to get the info so that I could understand how to tap in and give it the data to pass back to the caller.

bottom line is that the samples have different sets of scopes and claims in at least one place and that was the key problem.

the rest is learning how to use the scopes and scope claims to add to the user info endpoint for the applications needs.